# Unclear why crash consistent backups are unsafe for MySQL

Tags: mysql, vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, snapshot, innodb

My understanding of the InnoDB engine is that the database is always recoverable after a crash, due to the internal architecture of the engine itself. That is, InnoDB can correctly recover from a crash consistent state. I.e. if the power is pulled out.

On the other hand, when snapshotting a virtual machine in vSphere, common wisdom on the internet says that the backup will be crash consistent but may cause corruption of the InnoDB database unless the virtual machine is quiesced. This seems inconsistent with the above.

**Tldr; is InnoDB truly able to recover from a crash consistent state, and if so, shouldn't snapshotting a VM without quiescing be a safe backup method?**

Comment: Although a snapshot is very fast, it is not instant.  Does vSphere freeze things long enough to make it a true snapshot?

Comment: It does - it temporarily "stuns" the VM which freezes the memory and state until the snapshot is complete. Pretty amazing, actually

Comment: The secret sauce is in the "COW" -- Copy On Write.

Answer (score 1):

Never assume something is always recoverable and consistent!

Crash recovering an file system doesn't necessarily mean your files are intact. A (hopefully small) amount of uncommitted file system writes may be lost. Worst case, the metadata becomes inconsistent, and a fsck gets the file system back but may lose files. This also applies to your database logs, which depending on your recovery point objective may be problematic.

File consistency is a stronger claim: files are in a stable state. fsck should be already clean. A few ways to do this, VMware tools vmsync, Linux LVM snapshots or fsfreeze, Windows VSS.

Even files at a point in time does not imply application consistency. The database will have in memory updates not committed to disk. And new updates are always happening on a running system. Ideally, flush database writes to disk and suspend further writes, until the storage level snapshot is taken.

Or, sure it is possible to take an inconsistent backup and rely more on logs for recovery. This moves a little complexity from taking the backup to restoring it.

---

So far, I have assumed storage level backups, based on your choice of storage snapshots. A more complete evaluation of backup methods would look at both logical dumps and physical raw files. MariaDB's [A Quick   Start   Guide   to  Backup  Technologies](https://mariadb.com/files/A_Quick_Start_Guide_to_Backup_Technologies_-_MariaDB_White_Paper_-_08_26_13_001.pdf) compares
multiple implementations of each.  For example, have a look at how mylvmbackup does flush and snapshot, and how XtraBackup does redo log recovery.

Of course, backups are meaningless without restores. Always do a restore test. While doing so, verify the recovery point: what was the very last data recovered?

Answer (score 0):

Quiescing a guest consists in making sure all processes with pending I/O operations finish writting data to disk before actually allowing the ESXi snapshot operation to take place.

This implies coordination between the ESXi snapshot system, which is outer to the guest and the guest FS itself. This coordination is performed by **VMWare Tools**, or **open-vm-tools** (recommended) in Linux systems.

When a quiesced snapshot is performed and it returns no errors, you can be sure your data in the base disks is consistent, and so will be any backup performed in the disks below the current snapshot.

It is worth mentioning that quiescing of Linux systems requires nothing apart from open-vm-tools, it generally works out of the box, while Windows guests will need a number of additional services especific to the DB system you are using apart from VSS and Virtual Disk services.

Alternatives:

Some DB systems may not have bindings to work along with VMWare Tools in order to allow quiescing the database service. You have a number of alternatives to work around that issue.

1 - You may perform a cold backup, that is: stop the VM, take a snapshot and switch it on. The base data will be perfectly consistent, as the snapshot was taken on a switched off VM.

2 - You may stop the DB service and perform the guest backup, then switch it back on. Data will also be consistent, as the DB wasn't actually in use while the backup was being made.

3 - Set the DB server to read-only, then back it up, set it back to R&W mode.

4 - Take a snapshot, or a series of them in the guest FS. If you are using Windows Server, take some VSS snapshot before the backup takes place. If for some reason the backup data ends up being inconsistent, you can easily revert to the point previous to the VSS snapshot with consistent data.